# Replacing values in list of dict in dataframe column from other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe 1

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1221,"aptq",[{'id': 100051}, {'id': 100050}]]], columns = ["offid","name","sub_ids"])

   offid  name                           sub_ids
0   1221  aptq  [{'id': 100051}, {'id': 100050}]
```

Dataframe 2

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[100051, "zonal"], [100050, "upper"],
                    [100056, "capital | national"]], columns=["id", "name"])

       id                name
0  100051               zonal
1  100050               upper
2  100056  capital | national
```

Result DataFrame

```
offid          name                sub_ids
 1221          aptq         [zonal, upper]
```

Want to replace the values in sub_ids column of Dataframe 1 with the name of the id in DataFrame 2 to achieve result like Result Dataframe. Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) on `sub_ids`, then use [`Series.str.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) on column `sub_ids` to extract the values associated with key `id` from the dictionary, then using [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) map the `ids` to names in `df2`, and use [`Series.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) on `level=0` and `agg` using `list`:

```
names = (
    df1['sub_ids'].explode().str.get('id')
    .map(df2.set_index('id')['name']).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
)
df = df1.assign(sub_ids=names)
```

Result:

```
print(df)

   offid  name         sub_ids
0   1221  aptq  [zonal, upper]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1221,"aptq",[{'id': 100051}, {'id': 100050}]]], columns = ["offid","name","sub_ids"])
df2 =   pd.DataFrame([[100051,"zonal"],
[100050,"upper"],
[100056,"capital | national"]], columns = [    "id","name"])
df2 = df2.set_index("id").T.to_dict(orient='records')[0]
```

Now we just create a list and look for it in the dictionary:

```
df1["sub_ids"] = df1["sub_ids"].apply(lambda row: [item for sublist in [list(row[i].values()) for i in range(len(row))] for item in sublist] if len(row) > 0 else "-")
df1["sub_ids"]  = df1["sub_ids"].apply(lambda row:  [df2[row[i]] for i in range(len(row))] if len(row)>0 else "-")
df1

    offid   name    sub_ids
0   1221    aptq    [zonal, upper]
```